# LWC Default field values object layout

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, navigationmixin.navigate

I am trying to open a create new record layout from a lwc button, I need that this layout open with some field values prepopulated, I am using NavigationMixin Like this:

```
     this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Retencion__c',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state : {
                useRecordTypeCheck: 1,
                nooverride: '1',
                defaultFieldValues: defValString,
                navigationLocation: 'RELATED_LIST'
            }
        });
```

When my defValString variable is something like :

```
defvalString = 'field1__C = value1,field2__c = value2,field3__c = value3,value4,value5';
```

The problem is when a value for field have a comma ',' the value is shorted in the first comma, I think this is for comma separated format, are there any way to allow comma ',' in my values?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set value as JSON object.

```
        const defValString = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
            field1__C = value1,
            field2__c = value2,
            field3__c = 'value3,value4,value5'
        });

     this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Retencion__c',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state : {
                useRecordTypeCheck: 1,
                nooverride: '1',
                defaultFieldValues: defValString,
                navigationLocation: 'RELATED_LIST'
            }
        });
```

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-navigate-default.html